# JavaScript only working with Index action MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to develop a Mvc4 application and it has a javascript to show a random tips. but these javascript only work, when call by Index action. I want to work javascript with other actions. Please help to do this.

Here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JQuaryError.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the View with the javascript

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      this.randomtip = function () {

          var pause = 3000; // define the pause for each tip (in milliseconds) Feel free to make the pause longer so users can have time to read the tips :)
          var length = $("#tips li").length;
          var temp = -1;

          this.getRan = function () {
              // get the random number
              var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * length) + 1;
              return ran;
          };
          this.show = function () {
              var ran = getRan();
              // to avoid repeating tips we need to check 
              while (ran == temp) {
                  ran = getRan();
              };
              temp = ran;
              $("#tips li").hide();
              $("#tips li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").fadeIn("fast");
          };
          // initiate the script and also set an interval
          show(); setInterval(show, pause);

      };

      $(document).ready(function () {
          randomtip();
      });
</script>


}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ul id="tips">
        <li>... if you want to become a better coder you need to eat your vegetables?</li>
        <li>... it takes more time to code a web page then to make a pizza?</li>
        <li>... you should validate your code?</li>
        <li>... jQuery is your friend? For real!</li>
        <li>... no matter what some people claim, you can't learn CSS in 3 hours?</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've only included your JavaScript code on one view `.cshtml` file, it's only going to be loaded for that action's view. As you likely know, when the controller executes `return View();` in each action, it will return the view with the same name as the ActionResult method. Since MVC is stateless, no state information is passed around when you move from one page on your app to another, so no scripts/css/whatever else will be retained when you move between views. This means that for each action, you'll need to include the scripts in the corresponding `.cshtml` file.

That said, if you know you want to include it in *every* view, you can create a layout view that all your views will use. That way, you could put the JavaScript scripts that you want used on all views in the layout, and you won't have to duplicate that in each individual view.